# Autoencoders to crypt any type of data and Dimensionality reduction method through autoencoders

Tags: python, keras

We need to implement a new approach  using a generative deep learning model based on autoencoders to crypt any type of data And the idea is to use autoencoders to reduce dimensions of data so is it possible and how???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes! Autoencoders can be a solution for representing one information into another representation.

Autoencoders are a unsupervised learning technique where the goal is to make the input and output have the same value. So what is the use of autoencoders? They have hidden layers, usually with a smaller number of dimensions and the data is cloudy during this phase. You can still reconstruct the original data using the second part of the ANN, the decoder.

The ideia is:
original data > input layer > hidden layer (different number of nodes) > output layer > original data

The input and hidden layer: encoder
The hidden layer and output layer: decoder

Here you can find more information:
https://towardsdatascience.com/applied-deep-learning-part-3-autoencoders-1c083af4d798

One way would be to use a big hidden layer, higher than the data dimension in order to create an "encrypted" version, but I really don't see the point if you can use classical cryptography.

Comment: and do u think it's easy to implement it ? so i can crypt images or any type of data !!

Comment: Implementing is reliatively easy, the biggest issue is training the neural network. You need to understand it wont be able to crypt anything, like classic sha algorithm, the autoencoder must be train for the specific data.

Comment: Check this paper: "Digital Cryptography Implementation using Neurocomputational Model with Autoencoder Architecture" by Francisco Quinga Socasi